# How to get json data of product detail from website?

Tags: python, json, python-re

I am trying to get JSON data of products from the [website](https://www.trendyol.com). The code worked for around 400 - 500 products. But the one which is in the screenshot gives "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'" error for [this](https://www.trendyol.com/xiaomi/64mp-note-9-pro-6gb-64gb-6-67-yesil-akilli-cep-telefonu-p-58882069) product. I think the problem occurring because of double quotation. I could not escape from it. I tried (\ ") that one. But it still throws the error. How can I fix it?

[Error's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/293qK.jpg)

## The Code:

```
import re,json,requests

r = requests.get("https://www.trendyol.com/xiaomi/64mp-note-9-pro-6gb-64gb-6-67-yesil-akilli-cep-telefonu-p-58882069")
data = json.loads(re.search(r'PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=(.*?\}\});', r.text).group(1))
```

Comment: The question is why you have `None` and try to access a field of it that obviously doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you your comment helped a lot. I could not solve the reason. If I can, Why am I  create a topic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression you were using is not matching the actual JavaScript source in the file.

With

```py
re.search(r'PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__ = ({.*\}\});', r.text)
```

or, better

```py
re.search(r'PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__[\s]*=[\s]*({.*\}\})[\s]*;', r.text)
```

you will match the actual beginning of the JSON which is

```
        window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__ = {"product":{"attributes":[{"k
                                                   ^^^^
```

with spaces around the `=`.

Usage of HTML parsing or Selenium seems overdone for this use case, because you are anyway hacking into something that was never designed to be an interface and can change from one day to the other.

Rather, for fiddling with one-off regular expressions, use tooling like https://regex101.com to get right in controlled environment :)

Comment: Thank you. The regex is a bit hard. :) I will try the tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Selenium to get the value directly as a dictionary:

```py
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> 
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get("https://www.trendyol.com/xiaomi/64mp-note-9-pro-6gb-64gb-6-67-yesil-akilli-cep-telefonu-p-58882069")
>>> 
>>> ret = driver.execute_script('return window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__;')
>>> 
>>> driver.quit()
>>> 
>>> ret.keys()
dict_keys(['configuration', 'htmlContent', 'product', 'user'])
>>> ret['user']
{'isBuyer': False, 'loggedIn': False}
>>> ret['product'].keys()
dict_keys(['alternativeVariants', 'attributes', 'brand', 'brandCategoryBanners', 'breadcrumb', 'businessUnit', 'campaign', 'category', 'color', 'contentDescriptions', 'deliveryInformation', 'description', 'favoriteCount', 'gender', 'hasHtmlContent', 'hasStock', 'id', 'images', 'isBasketDiscount', 'isDigitalGood', 'isFreeCargo', 'isMarketplace', 'isRunningOut', 'isSellable', 'landings', 'maxInstallment', 'merchant', 'metaBrand', 'name', 'nameWithProductCode', 'originalCategory', 'otherMerchants', 'price', 'productCode', 'productGroupId', 'productStamps', 'promotions', 'questionsUrl', 'ratingScore', 'reviewsUrl', 'scheduledDelivery', 'sellerQuestionEnabled', 'seoContent', 'seoMeta', 'showSexualContent', 'showStarredAttributes', 'showVariants', 'tax', 'url', 'uxLayout', 'variants'])
>>> ret['product']['tax']
18
>>> ret['product']['name']
'64mp Note 9 Pro 6gb/64gb 6.67" Yeşil Akıllı Cep Telefonu'
```

Comment: Then use error handling and only use Selenium when your regular expression fails. Besides, you can use one running instance of Selenium for all links in a loop. Selenium is only slow for the initial opening of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The code is below.

```
from lxml import HTML
import requests, json

page = requests.get('https://www.trendyol.com/xiaomi/64mp-note-9-pro-6gb-64gb-6-67-yesil-akilli-cep-telefonu-p-58882069')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content.decode("utf8"))
products = tree.xpath('/html/body/script[3]/text()')
fi = products[0].find('{')
li = products[0].rfind('};') + 1
data = products[0][fi:li]
product = json.loads(data)
print(product["product"])
```